# Model parameter passed (HTTP POST) to Web API 2 from AngularJS is null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am making a POST request from Angular to Web API 2:

```
let params = { 
    ReportName: reportName,
    ParamName: paramName,
    ParamValues: paramValues
};
this.$http.post("/reportsweb/api/reports/", params).then(response => {
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
}, response => {
    deferred.reject(response);
})
```

Web API method is defined like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDependentParameterValues([FromBody]ArgumentModel args)
    {
            // args here is null for some reason
    }
```

where ArgumentModel is defined the same way as **params** var in Angular:

```
public class ArgumentModel
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    public string ParamValues { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I hit a breakpoint in WebAPI method, I see that args = null :(

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Here is the screenshot from angular app:

[image]

Comment: If you inspect the request in the network tab - do you see your data being passed in the payload?

Comment: yes, attached a screenshot

Comment: Use your browser development tools to see what is being sent. Based on the screenshot maybe you are using Chrome? Use the network tab to see the full Http request including the content-header and message body. You can also use PostMan or Fiddler to capture the http request and resend it or create your own to test outside of the browser.

Comment: `ParamValues` is an array in your screenshot - but defined as a string - fix that.

Comment: Yes, u'r right, thanks!